# Как сконвертировать QMap'ы имеющие один и тот же тип ключа и разные типы указателей как значения?

Tags: c++, qt, шаблоны-с++

Например, у меня есть класс `Item`, унаследованный от `QObject`.

Как проще сконвертировать `QMap<QString, Item *>` в `QMap<QString, QObject *>`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто в лоб передать из одного в другой:

```
QMap<QString, Item *> map1;
map1["1"] = new Item();
map1["2"] = new Item();
map1["3"] = new Item();

QMap<QString, QObject *> map2;

for (QString key : map1.keys()) {
    map2[key] = map1[key];
}

qDebug() << map1;
qDebug() << map2;
```

Консоль:

```
QMap(("1", QObject(0x7997d98))("2", QObject(0x7997f28))("3", QObject(0x7997fc0)))
QMap(("1", QObject(0x7997d98))("2", QObject(0x7997f28))("3", QObject(0x7997fc0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `std::map` очень просто:

```
 std::map<QString, Item   *> items;
 // где-нибудь берем items
 item["one"] = new Item(...);
 item["two"] = new Item(...);
 // ...

 std::map<QString, Object *> objects(items.begin(), items.end());
```

Qt сейчас нет под рукой и проверить не могу, но на 99% он так же будет работать так как стремится к совместимости со стандартными контейнерами.

И еще, не мое дело конечно, но смысла использовать контейнеры Qt нет никакого. Сам Qt в интерфейсах их использует очень слабо, за исключением QString и QVariant конечно. Контейнеры эти никаких преимуществ не дают, только лишняя завязка на Qt.

Comment: Увы, у `QMap` нет такого конструктора.
"_Контейнеры эти никаких преимуществ не дают_". Implicit sharing, java-style итераторы, foreach?